# Data.table: join a "long format" multi-time point table with a single time point table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following two `data.tables`:

```
mult.year <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                        time=rep(1:3, 3),
                        A=rnorm(9),
                        B=rnorm(9))
setkey(mult.year, id)
single <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3), 
                     C.3=rnorm(3))
setkey(single, id)
```

I want to join the two tables, so that the variable `C.3` only appears for `mult.year[time == 3]`

I can psuedo do this by assigning a new column:

```
mult.year[time == 3, C := single[,C.3]]
```

but I lose the `join` functionality: it requires all the `id`s to be in both datasets. Is there a way to do this while maintaining the join functionality?

Using the above tables, I'm trying to get this:

```
   id time          A          B        C.3
1:  1    1 -1.0460085  0.0896452         NA
2:  1    2  0.2054772  1.5631978         NA
3:  1    3 -1.7574449  0.5661457  0.6495645
4:  2    1  0.4171095 -0.2182779         NA
5:  2    2 -0.9238671  0.8263605         NA
6:  2    3 -0.5452715 -0.5842541 -1.5233764
7:  3    1  0.1793009  1.4399366         NA
8:  3    2  0.3438980  1.7419869         NA
9:  3    3  0.1067989  0.7630496  1.9658157
```

Comment: what do you mean by "C.3 only appears for `time==3`?". One of  `mult.year[time==3][single]` or `mult.year[single, C.3 := ifelse(time==3,C.3,NA)]` will probably suffice but your question is not clear which

Comment: It's the latter I'm after, I'll add some expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to include `time` in your data.table's key, you could do this:

```
## Add time ...
setkeyv(mult.year, c("id", "time"))                     ## ... to mult.year's key
single <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3), time=3, C.3=rnorm(3)) ## ... and to indexing dt

## Which will set up a simple call to [.data.table
mult.year[single, C.3:=C.3]
mult.year
#    id time          A           B         C.3
# 1:  1    1 -0.6264538 -0.30538839          NA
# 2:  1    2  0.1836433  1.51178117          NA
# 3:  1    3 -0.8356286  0.38984324  0.61982575
# 4:  2    1  1.5952808 -0.62124058          NA
# 5:  2    2  0.3295078 -2.21469989          NA
# 6:  2    3 -0.8204684  1.12493092 -0.05612874
# 7:  3    1  0.4874291 -0.04493361          NA
# 8:  3    2  0.7383247 -0.01619026          NA
# 9:  3    3  0.5757814  0.94383621 -0.15579551
```

Alternatively, to leave both `single` and your current key intact, use the approach suggested in mnel's comment above:

```
mult.year[single, C.3 := ifelse(time==3,C.3,NA)]
mult.year
#    id time          A           B       C.3
# 1:  1    1 -0.6264538 -0.30538839        NA
# 2:  1    2  0.1836433  1.51178117        NA
# 3:  1    3 -0.8356286  0.38984324 0.8212212
# 4:  2    1  1.5952808 -0.62124058        NA
# 5:  2    2  0.3295078 -2.21469989        NA
# 6:  2    3 -0.8204684  1.12493092 0.5939013
# 7:  3    1  0.4874291 -0.04493361        NA
# 8:  3    2  0.7383247 -0.01619026        NA
# 9:  3    3  0.5757814  0.94383621 0.9189774
```

Answer (score 2):

a more efficient solution would be to think of join types (sql style, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) read here for reference, as it helped me enormously to take use of `data.table` capabilities; then, take a look at `data.table` FAQ (point 2.16) how to achieve the needed join).

then, in fact, what you want, is that data.table `single` would be constructed the following way:

```
single <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3),time=3,C.3=rnorm(3))
```

right? and then, what you want is a left join with respect to `mult.year`, that is:

```
mult.year<-single[mult.year]
```

gives what you want. this approach is both more clear and efficient. for comparison:

```
> system.time(mult.year[single, C.3:=C.3])
user  system elapsed 
0.02    0.00    0.01
```

while my approach yields:

```
> system.time(mult.year<-single[mult.year])
user  system elapsed 
0       0       0
```

the difference though is in the order of columns are returned, but I believe this is a minor issue compared to speed gains if we consider a really huge chunk of data. hope that helps!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that you need to set the keys appropriately:

```
mult.year <- data.table(id=...,time=...,A=...,B=...,key=c("id","time"))
single <- data.table(id=...,time=3 ,C.3=...,key=c("id","time"))
```

the output in the final results is:

```
> print(mult.year)
   id time        C.3           A          B
1:  1    1         NA  0.02556433 -0.4525380
2:  1    2         NA  0.37282039 -1.5151395
3:  1    3  0.1769263 -1.48347426  0.5536820
4:  2    1         NA  0.85327700 -0.4924897
5:  2    2         NA -1.10516056  0.8360339
6:  2    3 -0.3698935  1.45610643 -0.9189147
7:  3    1         NA -0.53218378 -0.6740748
8:  3    2         NA  0.34124242 -1.1458312
9:  3    3 -1.3997742  0.32009017  0.4333386
```

Comment: Would you please show what key you gave to `single` and print the results you get from then doing `single[mult.year]`? When I run it (after first supplying `single` with a key, as it doesn't work at all without one), it gives results that don't match what the OP is  asking for...

Comment: see my edit. sorry for a mistake. I did forgot to mention the keys that I set.

Comment: Great, thanks. That looks good, though it might be easier for others to follow if you showed the reproducible code, including the keys you need to set, early in the post.